# HighCharts com problema

Tags: highcharts

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com problema ao trabalhar com highcharts. Algumas vezes ao implantar ele fica desta forma, como mostra a imagem acima, com as categorias erradas. Verifiquei o código e parece não ser ele o problema, acredito que seja algo na biblioteca, porem não sei o que exatamente pode ser.